# How to calculate the age of a user's input in years and months using php?

Tags: php

I have been given an assignment to build a point of sale system. The customer will be charged based on their age.If the user is older that 15.5 years they will be charge $50 for a product. If the user is younger that 15.5 years they will be charged $25.

This is the code that I have so far:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Age Test</title>
</head>
<body>

    <form action="age_test.php" method="post">

        <input type="text" name="first" placeholder="Enter first name">
        <br>
        <input type="text" name="last" placeholder="Enter last name">
        <br>
        <input type="date" name="date">
        <br>
        <label for="rush"> Check for a rush order(A $200 fee will apply.)</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="rush">
        <br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit">
    </form>

    <?php 
        if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
            // echo "submit is set";

            $date = $_POST['date'];

            $age = date("Y/m/d") - $date;

            echo $age;

            //Users age will determine the price.
        if($age >= 15.5){

        echo "<br>Your price is $50";


        }elseif ($age < 15.5) {
            echo "<br>Your price is $25";
        }

        if(isset($_POST['rush'])){
            // echo "<br>$200 is applied to payment";
        }


        }





     ?>

</body>
</html>
```

The solution that I have does not give me a decimal as a result. I would like some help on how to produce a decimal as a result. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the format of the date you expect users to enter?

Comment: The format is mm/dd/YYYY

Comment: My apologies I found an answer elsewhere and it was very help full. I simply converted the age into months that made it much easier to calculated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for the `number_format` function in this case.

```
string number_format ( float $number , int $decimals = 0 , string $dec_point = "." , string $thousands_sep = "," )
```

**Here's an example relevant to your assignment:**

```
number_format((float)$age, 2, '.', '');
```

Check out the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) for it.

Answer (score 0):

> Here's a way to calculate it, also considering the timezone.
>   I've updated the answer to calculate with **months** instead.

```
$dateInput = $_POST['date'];
$timeZone =  new DateTimeZone('America/New_York');

$bday = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y/m/d', $dateInput , $timeZone);

$diff = $bday->diff(new DateTime());

$months = $diff->format('%m') + 12 * $diff->format('%y');

//returned number of months and divide by 12.
//12 months make a year.

$age =  $months/ 12;
echo $age;
```

This will return a float by default.

> //And you can always round to 2 decimal places

```
echo number_format((float)$age, 2, '.', '');
```

Hope this helps

Comment: It seems he already has the code for determining the age, what he wants is a way to convert the number with one that has decimal points. Your answer gives him what he pretty much already has.

Comment: I've updated the answer to calculate with months instead. This will return a float by default.

Answer (score 0):

Try simple way :)

```
<?php

  $input = '1970/01/01'; // $_POST['date']

  $now = new \DateTime();

  $diff = $now->diff(new \DateTime($input));

  $price =  ($diff->y > 15 && $diff->m > 6) ?50 : 25;

  echo $price;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
// your date you  will display from database
$date = "2012-05-06";
$date = new DateTime($date);
/*
    * for the current year,month and day you will 
    * date('y') --> to print current day
    * date('m') --> to print the current month 
    * date('y') --> to print the current day 
*/
$y    = date('Y');
$m    = date('m');
$d    = date('d');
$full_date ='P'.$y.'Y'.$m.'M'.$d.'D';
/*
 for example 
  * we will subtract (2012-05-06) - (2017-07-26)
  * 
  * -0006 for year and 02 month and 20 day
  * 

*/
$date ->sub(new DateInterval(".$full_date."));

/*
    * you should ltrim (-) from years  
*/ 
$str = ltrim($date ->format('y'),'-');
/*
    * you should ltrim (0) from month  
*/ 

$str2 = ltrim($date ->format('m'),'0');
//output 1
echo $str.' years and '.$str2 .' months';
// output 2
echo $str.'.'.$str2;

?>
```

The output will be

```
6 years and 9 months
6.9
```

For more information about subtract date and time check this link [subtract date and time](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.sub.php)

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your calculation

```
 $age = date("Y/m/d") - $_POST['date'];
```

is that - regardless of the date format used on the client side - you are effectively trying to subtract two `string` values from each other, resulting in them implicitly being casted to `int`s.

That is, as long as both `string`s start with the year, the calculation *appears* to work; except that it never contains the fraction you are looking for.

See https://3v4l.org/qskMD for an example.

As a solution to your problem, try calculating the difference in years first, then find the remaining days, and divide by the number of days in a year:

```
// create a `DateTimeImmutable` object from the date provided (adjust format as needed)
$birthday = \DateTimeImmutable::createFromFormat(
    'Y-m-d',
    $_POST['date']
);

// current date and time
$now = new \DateTimeImmutable();

// find the total difference
$totalDifference = $now->diff($date);

// get difference in total years only
$years = (int) $difference->format('y');

// create a `DateTimeImmutable` object, going back full years from now only
$yearsAgo = $now->diff(new \DateInterval(sprintf(
    'P%sY',
    $years
));

// get difference between birthday and going back full years
$remainingDifference = $yearsAgo->diff($birthday);

// get difference in months
$months = $remainingDifference->format('m');

$age = $years + $months / 12;
```

For reference, see:

- http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetimeimmutable.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php

Comment: Adjusted this answer to point out the mistake you make when trying to subtract two `string`s.